# Problems with 'CALL' command on batch

Tags: command-line, call

Maybe a tricky question here now...

I have an script which asks for a mandatory string, that can't be empty. If it is empty, the script should return an error:

```
@echo off

set $my_var=

:my_question
cls
set /p $my_var="My question (mandatory): "
if not defined $my_var call :error_message

echo.
echo More code here
goto end

:error_message
echo.
powershell -command write-host "*********** ATTENTION ************" -background red -foreground yellow
echo.
echo Answer is mandatory. Press ENTER!
pause > nul
goto my_question

:end
echo.
set $my_var=
echo.
echo Ended
```

But if the user mistypes, let's say, 3 times, the code between the first `echo.` and `goto end` is repeated 3 times. The `:end` section is also repeated. The message in `:error_code` isn't repeated:

```
My question (mandatory): 6

More code here


Ended

More code here


Ended

More code here


Ended

More code here


Ended
```

It is ignoring even the `goto end` command! I want to avoid put the code for error_message between brackets, because I'll have to use a goto command, and maybe break my code, as it have much more than this.

What's wrong with "CALL"?

Comment: Don't have a proper test environment available right now… What happens, if you remove the `set $my_var=` or change (for testing) the after prompt check to `if defined $my_var call :error_message`?

Comment: Thank you. I can't test for now, as I did a workaround for this. I just put the code for error message in parentheses, and on a new line just after, I put a goto. ;)